# How Does Cisco IPS Work?

Tags: intrusion-detection, ips, intrusion-prevention

How does it work? Does it typically have predefined patterns of trusted or malicious activity? Is it actually a category of firewall techniques? I am more curious about Cisco than I am about other products..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cisco IPS basically uses "signatures" which are nothing more than [regular expressions](https://supportforums.cisco.com/community/netpro/security/intrusion-prevention/blog/2010/12/23/introduction-to-regular-expressions-for-ips).

Comment: Of course.  I'm not always crotchety..